# Invalid hook cal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, use-effect

I am using Gatsby with the CSS framework Bulma, In order for the Mobile navbar to work, you have to add an event listener for a button that only becomes available when to screens size is a certain dimension. in previous versions of Gatsby, it worked fine, only in the recent week have I been running to problems. Now I get an Invalid hook call

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'

let Header = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        let burger = document.getElementById(`burger`);
        let menu = document.getElementById(`navMenu`)
        burger.addEventListener(`click`, function () {
            burger.classList.toggle(`is-active`);
            menu.classList.toggle(`is-active`)
        })
    });

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar is-fixed-top" id="navbar">
                <div className="navbar-brand">
                    <Link to="/">
                        <p className="navbar-item">CMJR DEVELOPMENT</p>
                    </Link>

                    <a role="button" id="burger" className="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="navbar-menu" id="navMenu">
                    <div className="navbar-end">
                        <Link to={"/service"} className="navbar-item ">Services</Link>
                        <Link to={"/portfolio"} className="navbar-item ">Portfolio</Link>
                        <Link to={"/contact"} className="navbar-item ">Contact</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Header;

I know I'm doing something wrong, just not what.
```

Comment: The `useEffect` call is completely unnecessary, just assign the event handlers in the JSX. You can keep the toggled state in a couple of `useState` states if you wish. Also note that your current setup will set the event handler over and over again on every single render.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did what you said and it worked. I'm still learning React so sometimes I run into problems, Thanks again